# SAS Date Compare Function

Tags: sql, sas

I have created a table with 2 columns, a value field ($char19.) and a date field (date9.).

I can't figure out how to write a SAS program to give me all rows that are greater than the first day of the month 13 months ago. If today is 5/4/16 I want all values greater than 4/30/15.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the today() function? If not, check it out: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245961.htm

Comment: do you want greater than 4/30/15 or greater than 5/1/15?

Comment: @RawFocus I want to include 5/1/15

Comment: The problem is the same as the above, except with "MONTH" instead of "QUARTER", and -13 or -14 (not sure which you want) instead of -1.

Comment: if yourDateVar gt intnx('month',today(),-13,'end');